# Laravel : Differing response to AJAX request per server

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have the **exact** same code running on two different servers, with the route returning a collection to an AJAX call. On my local machine, the response comes through as an array but on the remote and a coworker's machine it comes through as an Object.

Definitely the same code (pushed from local, pulled to remote)
The collections are definitely in the same format (did a dd() and they're the same)
The request and response headers are the same

It works on the remote if I DON'T sort the collection first, but that makes no difference to my local, and the dd()s look exactly the same.

Local response example (15 entries):

```
[{id: 80, title: "Banner, Bruce", eventColor: "green", order: 1, availability: false},.....]
```

Remote response example (29 entries)

```
{"0":{"id":18,"title":"Bond, James","eventColor":"green","order":1,"availability":false},.....}
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/roster/' + roster_type + '/resources',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: true,
            cache: true,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (resources) {

            // This line right here works fine on my machine because the array has a length,
            // not on the remote where resources.length is undefined
            if(resources.length > 10 && view.type == 'resourceTimeGrid') {
               changeView('resourceTimelineDay');
            }
            
            successCallback(resources);
            getRosterEvents();
        }).fail(response => {
            showErrorMessage(response);
            failureCallback(response);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `sortBy` method sorts the collection by the given key. **The sorted
> collection keeps the original array keys,** so in this example we'll
> use the `values` method to reset the keys to consecutively numbered
> indexes:

(Source: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sortby - emphasis mine)

Using `values()` resets the array indexes, so JavaScript then sees a nice numbered array.